# YouTube iframe embed with PhoneGap on iOS 6 shows only empty advertisement screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, video, youtube, ios6

I'm trying to implement a youtube video for a PhoneGap application, so I am using google's recommended iFrame implementation. On iOS 5, Android 2.3 and 4.0 this solution works perfectly, however on iOS 6 it fails. It shows an empty advertisement box without further clickthrough, it's as if the youtube code is not recognising the iPhone 5 with iOS 6 as a mobile device.

I have attached a screenshot and the applied code. Does anyone else have this problem or an idea on how to solve it?

[image: PhoneGap YouTube iframe implementation on iOS6]

```
 <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="100%"  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zG59U7asvCE" frameborder="0">
           </iframe>
```

Comment: Fixed: I forgot to add the *.ytimg.com url to the info.plist file for whitelisted URLs :-)